# Помогите реализовать нечетный поиск в таблицу sql server entity framework 6 WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, сервер, entity-framework

Долго не могу реализовать поиск данных в C# WPF SQL SERVER, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе ключевого слова в текстовое поле, в DataGrid отображались совпадающие данные из таблицы SQL?

Comment: что конкретно значит `совпадающие данные`?

Comment: `Нечетный поиск` - имелось ввиду "Нечеткий поиск"?

Comment: Как вариант, если не нужна хитрая логика поиска, то `db.tableName.Where(p => p.fieldName.Contains(searchKey))`

Comment: Да, нечеткий ((. Я чот, не заметил (